# ASP.NET MVC 3 app on IIS6

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, .net-4.0, iis-6

I have hosted .NET 4.0 / ASP.NET MVC 3 app on IIS 6 on Windows SErver 2003 machine. When I browse the app i get below error:

> Access to the path 'C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\' is denied.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAtbd.png]

I have installed .net 4.0 on machine and when I checked the path referred in error I don't see .net 4.0 folder there. So it's very confusing and not able to figure out where is the problem? 
I would appreciate if anyone can help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue got solved when I installed MVC3 on my server.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is about permissions or something. Will you at least try to impersonate web application to a user who has access permission to the referenced folder?

[You can find information about impersonation here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292118%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I'd first start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). If that doesn't help then you need to grant access to that folder to the account that runs the ASP.Net service (ASPNET???).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like when the first version of .net was installed with the reference assemblies the permissions weren't properly set on it. Its just simply a matter of changing permissions.
aspnet_regiis as previously mentioned won't work here, this is a folder used as a local reference path when you add references to libraries in the GAC. When you click "add reference" in visual studio - all the gac libraries that show up are from this location, it is not actually querying the gac (you can also set registry keys to customize that location as well). Just follow these directions to change permissions on that folder and subfolders and you should be good. if you still have an issue edit your question and post the new error msg

http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/denied-access-to-iis-directories